# OpenMDAO: First Steps

Tags: installation, anaconda, openmdao

I am new in the world of OpenMDAO (and also on Python) and I am having some problems to understand the use of the software. I have already installed Anaconda (pyth v2.7) and the OpenMDAO, but I don't know how to run it. I am following [this tutorial](http://openmdao.org/releases/0.1.0/docs/user-guide/simple_example.html) but I am not sure if I am doing it properly. I write the .py files in notepad++, and I try to run on the IPython but when I use the command : `from paraboloid import Paraboloid` it appears an error : `No module named.api`. I think that maybe I am not using the correct path (I'm in the folder where I have the .py files). Probably it's an stupid error, so sorry for the question.

Thank you all, Jose M O

Comment: Can we take a look at your input file for Paraboloid? I think it would help us find out what is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your tutorial link above is correct, I see that you are using a tutorial for OpenMDAO 0.1.0.  That version is 5.5 years old at this time, and is no longer supported.  We will be happy to help with your questions, but to get a better foundation, and a much more useful tool, please consider:

1. Install OpenMDAO 1.5.0 (`pip install openmdao` or read these [installation docs](http://openmdao.readthedocs.org/en/1.5.0/getting-started/install.html))
2. Try [this paraboloid tutorial](http://openmdao.readthedocs.org/en/1.5.0/usr-guide/tutorials/paraboloid-tutorial.html) instead.

Good luck,

Keith

NOTE: If you installed OpenMDAO 1.x.x and are using the tutorial from 0.1.0, you would have many problems with api imports, as many things have changed since 0.1.0.